# pure LuaXml find function equivalent

Tags: xml, lua

I am trying to rebuild the `find` function from the [luaxml](http://viremo.eludi.net/LuaXML/) module. I am a little bit stuck, it's one of my first attempts with lua.

This is how LuaXML works:

```
require('LuaXml');

response= '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?> \
    <GeraeteAntwort AntwortType="Input" RequestID="2" Result="Success"> \
      <Output AusgabeDevice="Display"AusgabeResult="Success"></Output> \
      <Input Eingabe="Keyboard" EinResult="Success"> \
        <InputValue> \
          <InString>True</InString> \
        </InputValue> \
      </Input> \
    </GeraeteAntwort>'


local xfile = xml.eval(response)
local xInput = xfile:find("Input")
for k,v in pairs(xInput) do print(k,v) end
```

With the result table from the find function I can access the attributes of `input` (like *Eingabe*) with  `xInput.Eingabe`. And now comes the tricky part. I can do:

```
local xIN = xInput:find("InputValue")
```

which gives me the attributes of the InputValue tag. Then I can access the result with

```
xIN:find('InString')[1]
```

Short: I can also do the find on the result of a find.

This is the part I don't know how to do.

I use an XML lib for parsing and tried to modify it.
I uploaded this on an [pastie](http://pastie.org/private/uutlpsdf6dnhiwpvvjx6za).

```
xfile = XL:new()
xfile:from_string(response)
local xInput = xfile:find("Input")
```

This allows me to access all the attributes from Input. But I can't make another find on that to get the InputValue.

How can i do this?